# How to debug a semop failure?

Tags: php, gentoo, gdb, strace, semaphore

Using a `2.6.30-gentoo-r4` Linux a very complex system of `php` code is executed (with 4.4.9-pl0-gentoo and 5.2.10-pl0-gentoo), which occasionally runs into a semaphore blocking problem. The call to the `php` function `sem_acquire` is blocked, bringing the system ultimately to a crash.

However, this semaphore in question does not seem to be blocked by another `php` process, which led me to investigate further. I was able to identify the `php` process in question and to `strace` it, leading to the blocking semaphore:

```
....
09:03:25 gettimeofday({1415696605, 778078}, NULL) = 0
09:03:25 close(5)                       = 0
09:03:25 gettimeofday({1415696605, 778483}, NULL) = 0
09:03:25 gettimeofday({1415696605, 778708}, NULL) = 0
09:03:25 semop(0, 0xbf8f1692, 1 <unfinished ...>
```

This particular output `semop(0, 0xbf8f1692, 1)` is not of much help to me, since I cannot see the content of `struct sembuf` (second argument to `semop`). Maybe someone else sees a problem directly with this `semop` call?

Anyway, I continued the investigation to check the memory at address `0xbf8f1692` (as root):

```
> gdb --pid 1236   
GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i586-pc-linux-gnu".
Attaching to process 1236
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
(gdb) dump memory /root/output 0xbf8f1692 0xbf9f1692 
(gdb) quit
> hexdump -C output 
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00100000
```

Does this mean the `semop` is called with a `struct sembuf` pointing to a bunch zeros? Or did I do something wrong to find out the memory to see what the arguments to `semop` are? Are there different ways to see what is going on in that `semop` call?

**Additional information:**

- The Linux system neither knows the command `prctl` nor `ptrace`.
- A directory named `/proc/sys/kernel/yama` does not exist (see [suggested information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#ptrace_Protection)).

Comment: `ptrace not PERMITTED` sounds like you are using gdb with the wrong uid.

Comment: I am calling `gdb` as root. Could I still be using the wrong uid?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#ptrace_Protection uid is not the problem. You have to allow ptrace for your session.

Comment: @Nils: I updated the question. I have neither the commands `prctl` nor the command `ptrace` on the system in question, and also the directory `/proc/sys/kernel/yama` does not exist. I need to either allow `ptrace`(?) more rights, or I need another way to read specific memory allocated by a process.

Comment: Possible solution: http://www.totalnetsolutions.net/2012/06/26/gdb-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/